# Plot NumPy ndarray into a 3D surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a `numpy.ndarray` of size 200x200. I want to plot it as a 3D surface where x and y are indexes of the array and z is the value of that array element. Is there any easy way to do it or do I have to transform my array into a long list?

Comment: You can trivially get a contour plot with matplotlib's `contour` or `matshow`. For a truly 3d plot, have a look at the [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) submodule.

Answer (score 0):

For example using matplotlib:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

#your index 
x = np.linspace(1, 200, 200);
y = np.linspace(1, 200, 200)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y);     #making a grid from it

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)      #make some calculations on the grid
Z = np.sin(R)                 #some more calculations
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-5, 5)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

However, as your array is already quite large, you might want to consider a different plotting tool like [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html). matplotlib usually puts a copy of your complete array into the plot. That's memory demanding when dealing with big data. But I'm not sure, whether `mayavi` does the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mayavi and plot your array as a plane with different colors representing the values. It would look like this:

```
import numpy
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.imshow(yourarray)
mlab.show()
```

Alternative you can create points with an elevation from the ground plane and get a fitting plane through the points. See [here:http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html#example-surface-from-irregular-data](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html#example-surface-from-irregular-data)

What is best for you depends on the continuity of your data.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to plot a 3D surface on top of a 2D grid what you could do is something similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# create some fake data    
array_distribution3d = np.ones((200, 200))
array_distribution3d[0:25, 0:25] = -1

# create the meshgrid to plot on
x = np.arange(0, array_distribution3d.shape[0])
y = np.arange(0, array_distribution3d.shape[1])

# here are the x,y and respective z values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = []
for i in range(0, array_distribution3d.shape[0]):
    z_y = []
    for j in range(0, array_distribution3d.shape[1]):
        z_y.append(array_distribution3d[i, j])

    z.append(z_y)
Z = np.array(z)

# create the figure, add a 3d axis, set the viewing angle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(45, 60)

# here we create the surface plot
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

However, to the best of my knowledge, this kind of data can be plotted as a colourmap.
This can be plotted as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import os.path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array_distribution = np.ones((200, 200))
array_distribution[0:25, 0:25] = -1
fig = plt.imshow(array_distribution)
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.035, pad=0.035, ticks=[-1., 0., 1.])
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0, 200])
figure = plt.gcf()
file = os.path.join('demo1.png')
figure.savefig(file, dpi=250)
plt.close('all')
print('done')
```